# Biblatex Automatically Suppressing Several Types of Bibliographic Information (all the fields with "OPT")

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, biblatex-chicago, bibliographystyle

I am having a problem with Biblatex in which is only printing part of the information types supplied in my .bib file.

For example, the printed bibliography has: Booij, Geert (2005). *The Grammar of Words*
But the .bib file has: @book{Booij,
author = {Geert Booij},
title = {The Grammar of Words},
year = {2005},
OPTpublisher = {Oxford University Press},
OPTlocation = {Oxford},
}

It is not printing any of the sections that begin with OPT for any entry.

This is what I have in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyFile.bib}
```

This is what I have where I want to print the bibliography:

```
\pagebreak
\uspunctuation
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={References}
]
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: When I go to Bibliography --> Biblatex --> Single-Volume Book, this is what it produces. It produces something similar for all the other information types.

```
@book{•,
author = {•},
title = {•},
year = {•},
OPTeditor = {•},
OPTeditora = {•},
OPTeditorb = {•},
OPTeditorc = {•},
OPTtranslator = {•},
OPTannotator = {•},
OPTcommentator = {•},
OPTintroduction = {•},
OPTforeword = {•},
OPTafterword = {•},
OPTsubtitle = {•},
OPTtitleaddon = {•},
OPTmaintitle = {•},
OPTmainsubtitle = {•},
OPTmaintitleaddon = {•},
OPTlanguage = {•},
OPToriglanguage = {•},
OPTvolume = {•},
OPTpart = {•},
OPTedition = {•},
OPTvolumes = {•},
OPTseries = {•},
OPTnumber = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTpublisher = {•},
OPTlocation = {•},
OPTisbn = {•},
OPTchapter = {•},
OPTpages = {•},
OPTpagetotal = {•},
OPTaddendum = {•},
OPTpubstate = {•},
OPTdoi = {•},
OPTeprint = {•},
OPTeprintclass = {•},
OPTeprinttype = {•},
OPTurl = {•},
OPTurldate = {•},
}
```

Comment: That's weird. I have no idea. When I'm in my .bib file and click Bibliography --> Biblatex --> and then click whichever citation type I need (let's say "single-volume book", it produces what I just put in the question (it was too long to paste here). @DG'

Comment: I'm using MacTeX, TeXMaker, and TeXLive2020. Everything is on the most recent update. @DG'

Comment: You must remove the `OPT`-part: `OPTeditor`→ `editor`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way for me to make it to where the OPT part does not show up in the first place?

Comment: That seems to be a TeXmaker default (entries beginning with OPT are ignored). I have no idea how to automatically remove the OPT part in TeXmaker. But you can run bibtool on you `.bib`-file to remove the prefix: `bibtool -r opt file.bib`

Comment: Thank you so much @DG'!